# Strongswan VPN with Checkpoint stuck on connecting

Tags: linux, firewall, strongswan, checkpoint

I am new to strongswan and linux so i'm trying to setup a vpn connection between a linux firewall cluster and a checkpoint gateway.

So this is my node list and resources:

> root@Deb-FW-C1:/etc# crm status
> Cluster Summary:
>
> - Stack: corosync
> - Current DC: fw-c2 (version 2.0.5-ba59be7122) - partition with quorum
> - Last updated: Sat Apr  1 12:04:28 2023
> - Last change:  Sat Apr  1 12:04:25 2023 by root via cibadmin on iantwy
> - 2 nodes configured
> - 3 resource instances configured
>
> Node List:
>
> - Online: [ fw-c2 fw-c1 ]
>
> Full List of Resources:
>
> - ping-gateway        (ocf::pacemaker:ping):   Started fw-c2
> - Resource Group: FW-CLUSTER:
> - FIREWALL  (lsb:firewall):  Started fw-c1
> - CL-VIP      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):        Started fw-c2

This is my /etc/ipsec.conf

> conn linux-to-cp
>
> > type=tunnel
> > leftupdown=/usr/local/sbin/ipsec.sh
> > mark=300
> > left=x.x.x.190
> > leftid=x.x.x.190
> > leftsubnet=192.168.3.0/24
> > right=x.x.x.201
> > rightsubnet=192.168.4.0/24
> > authby=secret
> >  keyexchange=ikev2
> >  ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024
> >  ikelifetime=28800s
> >  esp=aes128-sha1-modp1024
> >  lifetime=3600s
> >  dpddelay=10s
> >  dpdtimeout=30s
> >  dpdaction=restart
> > auto=start

ipsec.secrets

> #source          destination
> x.x.x.190 x.x.x.201:PSK
> "firewall-linux-pass"

When starting the ipsec:

> root@Deb-FW-C1:/etc# ipsec restart
> Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
> Starting strongSwan 5.9.1 IPsec [starter]...
> root@Deb-FW-C1:/etc# ipsec status
> Security Associations (0 up, 1 connecting):
> linux-to-cp[1]: CONNECTING, x.x.x.190[%any]...x.x.x.201[%any]

Systemctl status strongswan-starter

> root@Deb-FW-C1:/etc#  systemctl status strongswan-starter
> ● strongswan-starter.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/strongswan-starter.service; enabled; vendor >preset: enabled)
> Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2023-04-01 11:47:46 +04; 58min ago
> Process: 252511 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ipsec start --nofork (code=exited, >status=0/SUCCESS)
> Main PID: 252511 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> CPU: 12ms
>
> Apr 01 11:47:46 Deb-FW-C1 systemd[1]: Started strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon >using ipsec.conf.
> Apr 01 11:47:46 Deb-FW-C1 ipsec[252511]: Starting strongSwan 5.9.1 IPsec [starter]...
> Apr 01 11:47:46 Deb-FW-C1 ipsec_starter[252511]: Starting strongSwan 5.9.1 IPsec [starter]...
> Apr 01 11:47:46 Deb-FW-C1 ipsec_starter[252511]: charon is already running (/var/run/charon.pid exists) -- skipping daemon s>
> Apr 01 11:47:46 Deb-FW-C1 ipsec[252511]: charon is already running (/var/run/charon.pid exists) -- skipping daemon start
> Apr 01 11:47:46 Deb-FW-C1 ipsec[252511]: starter is already running (/var/run/starter.charon.pid exists) -- no fork done
> Apr 01 11:47:46 Deb-FW-C1 ipsec_starter[252511]: starter is already running (/var/run/starter.charon.pid exists) -- no fork >
> Apr 01 11:47:46 Deb-FW-C1 systemd[1]: strongswan-starter.service: Succeeded.

I configured the checkpoint on GUI and they both have the same encryption configuration and i created an interoperable object for the linux firewall and added the vpn rule to allow traffic through. I also added the IKE UDP port 500 and 4500 for IPSEC NAT. Also the shared secret key is the same as well.
But the issue might be in the config file in the linux firewall.

Any help on why it is stuck on connecting ?